# If statements not running

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

The strings were parsed to integers, so the condition of the if statements are properly right set. Why are the if statements not running? Why there doesn't appear a MessageDialog with a response?

```
 class process{
     public static void whoIs(){

         JFrame frame=new JFrame("The Oldest");
            String a=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter, please, the first name and age:", "QUIZ: Who is the Oldest", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
           String b=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter, please, the second name and age:", "QUIZ: Who is the Oldest", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);


            String age1=a.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
            String age2=a.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");



            String name1=a.replaceAll("\\d","");
            String name2=b.replaceAll("\\d","");


            int age1int=Integer.parseInt(age1);
            int age2int=Integer.parseInt(age2);



            if (age1int>age2int){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, name1+ " is the oldest!", "QUIZ: Who is the Oldest?", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

            if (age2int>age1int) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, name2+ " is the oldest!", "QUIZ: Who is the Oldest?", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

     }
}
```

Comment: it's trivial - just debug it, code is short and clean

Comment: or just print both condition and check

Comment: just print the values of age1int and age2int before the if statements and see their values. then you will understand

Comment: maybe the values are identical. we don't know what your input is, so we can only speculate.
also, use else if ( age2int > age1int) ...
it's a bit more efficiënt
why are you doing this:
String age1=a.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
            String age2=a.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
btw ?

Ruchira found it: you've used a for both, which means your ages 'll always be equal.

Comment: The kind of question that the "caused by a typo" close-vote reason was designed for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your both ages are same and your if condition will not match since you are not considering the equality. I think you missed this, Next time try with debugger then you can identify these kind of issues by your own.

```
 String age1=a.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
 String age2=a.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
```

This should change this to following.

```
  String age1=a.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
  String age2=b.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
```